# How to check if onresize method is set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, richfaces

Can I check if a onresize method was set?

I've previously used:

```
$(window).resize(function() { /* ... */ });
```

Due a unknown bug in another library, `onresize` is not called anymore. After executing above line it works perfectly again. The method is invoked once. If I execute the line in the Firebug console again, the method is invoked twice.

I would like to write a workaround, which sets `onresize` as soon as it's "reseted".

I'm looking for something like that: (undefined **or** null)

```
if (window.onresize == undefined) { /* ... */ }
```

The external library/framework is Richfaces 4 (Extended Data Table). As soon as I sort a column, some of the onresize function handler were gone.

Before:

```
$._data(window,'events').resize

// result on the Chrome console: 
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

After using sorting:

```
$._data(window,'events').resize

// result on the Chrome console: 
[Object]
```

I'm looking for a way to write a workaround.

**JIRA Issue**

- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13117 (fixed with future release 4.3.4)

Comment: As soon as it is reseted? What do you mean with that? You want to check if the screen is resized and trigger a function?

Comment: Something like: `if (window.onresize == undefined) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @ThomasZuberbühler Why would window.onresize be undefined? I'm pretty sure you _can't_ delete it. You mean someone deleted jQuery's .resize ? Or that someone overwrote _your_ function handler for onresize?

Comment: Why not use jQuery's `.on` and `.off` appropriately? Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @IanClark - +1, whenever someone needs to check if an event handler has been set, they are probably doing something else wrong.

Comment: Please see my edit on my question...

Comment: Fix the bug in the other library instead of working around it. Probably they're calling `$(window).off("resize")` without restricting it to their own event handlers.

Comment: It sounds like your plugin is calling `.off` without a namespace. Shout at the developer until they fix that. They are a bad developer.

Comment: Thank you. I've created an issue for the Richfaces developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$._data()` which is not a method publicly supported:

```
$(window).on('load',function() {
    if(!$._data(window,'events').resize)
        alert('none resize bound');
});
```

In older jquery version it was: `$.data()`

Comment: Why not just `$(window).data("events").['resize']`?

Comment: @IanClark That is not longer supported since jQuery 1.8.

Comment: @IanClark This is to avoid confusion with .data() method of DOM object than $.data() has been changed to $._data()  the '_' means internal method by convention.

Comment: @IanClark it doesn't because the $._data() method is not a public method

Comment: No, but I was asking why you can't use the `data()` method, looking at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/) I see no mention of that being depreciated

Answer (score 1):

what i used in my project was

```
 $(window).unbind('resize').bind('resize',function(){
//code here
});
```

it will remove all the previously bind (registered) handlers for resize event and register this new function as the handler.
this approach is useful only when you want to attach a single event handler.

Comment: That looks exactly like the bug in that other library.

Comment: "of course use it when you want only one resize handler". Please use the namespaces. They exist for a reason you know…

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers and comments. As suggested I went to the source of the problem and wrote for that a workaround including opening an issue.

```
window.RichFaces.ui.ExtendedDataTable.prototype.deActivateResizeListener = function() { 
   if (this.resizeEventName != undefined) { 
       $(window).off(this.resizeEventName); 
   } 
};
```

I accepted roasted answer since it really helped to find a workaround and his answer answered my question if there is a way to find out if a event handler is attached.